# Неправильно работают циклы While

Tags: python, while

Смотрите вот код питона:

```
f = open("text6.txt", 'wb')
spisok=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M']
count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0
count5=0
count6=0
while(count1<62):
 while(count2<62):
  while(count3<62):
   while(count4<62):
    while(count5<62):
     while(count6<62):
      f.write(spisok[count1])
      f.write(spisok[count2])
      f.write(spisok[count3])
      f.write(spisok[count4])
      f.write(spisok[count5])
      f.write(spisok[count6])
      f.write('\n')
      count6=count6+1
     count5=count5+1
    count4=count4+1
   count3=count3+1
  count2=count2+1
 count1=count1+1
f.close
```

То есть должен перебирать слова от 000000 до MMMMMM
Но он перебирает только от 000000 до 00000M
покажите правильный синтаксис вложенного цикла

Comment: 6(!) вложенных циклов...месье знает толк в извращениях

Comment: а почему не использовать for ? И красивее, и понятнее

   for count1 in spisok:
     f.write(count1)

(count1 - теперь символ, а не индекс).

Правда есть ещё проще способ (в плане записи, но не в плане "аааа, как это работает").

Comment: @KoVadim какой?

Comment: Подобные задачи решаются банальным инкременентом **одной** переменной и выводом этого числа в М-теричной системе счисления с добавлением в начало М-теричного числа нужного количества нулей.  
Алгоритм вывода в нужной системе счисления легко гуглится.

Answer (score 7):

Перед началом каждого вложенного цикла надо обнулять переменную, которая в нем изменяется, например:

```
while(count1<62):
 count2=0
 while(count2<62):
  ...
  count2 = count2+1
```

Answer (score 3):

мои варианты:)

```
spisok=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M']
r = [(a+b+c+d+e+f) for a in spisok for b in spisok for c in spisok for d in spisok for e in spisok for f in spisok]
```

теперь r будет содержать 56800235584 элементов (я сильно сомневаюсь, что это вместиться в оперативную память обычного компа). Поэтому, в данному случае лучше все таки циклы, чем такой генератор.

Если сохранить это на диск, по одному элементу на строку (то есть по 7 байт - ещё и перевод строки нужен) - получается 370 Гигабайт - не на все жесткие диски вместится.

Прикинем, сколько это будет писаться на диск. Исходим из того, что средняя скорость записи - 60Мб/с (она может быть и быстрее, если ssd). У меня получилось 14 часов (это если принебречь скоростью работы интерпретатора).

Итак, 370 Гигабайт, 14 часов в лучшем случае. Нужно ли оно?

Ок, пойдем дальше. Можно ли это записать коротко. Очень коротко.

```
import itertools

spisok=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M']

c = 0
for el in itertools.product(spisok, repeat=6):
    print "".join(el)
    c = c + 1
    if c>50:
        break
```

`c` нужен для того, что бы получить только несколько первых элементов. Основную работу делает `itertools.product`. Первый параметр - массив для повторов, а второй - сколько раз  "перемножать". Но можно и так написать `itertools.product("abc", "123", "zxc")`

Интересно то, что такой способ работает быстро - так как он не генерирует всю последовательность, а получает следующий элемент по мере надобности.

Comment: @KoVadim, интересно, сколько времени будет работать быстрый метод на Питоне?

Я попробовал на Си, с разной длиной и количеством счетчиков (естественно, не 6 вложенных циклов) и вывод в /dev/null

     $ gcc -O3 tloops.c -std=gnu99
     $ time ./a.out 4 >/dev/null
     counters: 4  length: 62
     real 0m0.661s
     user 0m0.656s
     sys 0m0.000s
     $ time ./a.out 5 >/dev/null
     counters: 5  length: 62
     real 1m0.481s
     user 1m0.076s
     sys 0m0.404s
     $ time ./a.out 6 32 >/dev/null
     counters: 6  length: 32
     real 1m3.485s
     user 1m3.180s
     sys 0m0.292s

CPU i5-250

Comment: у меня процессор послабее на ноуте (Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4200  @ 2.00GHz) и 4x62 проходит за 1.7-2.1 секунды (тело цикла пустое, просто pass) 5x62 = 105-110 сек. Учитывая, что проц у меня слабее, не так уж и плохо.

Comment: Да, шустрый питон.

Comment: питон шустрый до тех пор, пока по максимуму используются встроенные средства. Как только пытаемся писать полностью свой велосипед - скорость падает катастрофически.

Comment: Вот этим-то и надо бы заняться... 

AI, распознавание алгоритма поведения объекта/субъекта, выработка  оптимального плана взаимодействия (на примере питон-компилятора с генерацией машинного кода для параллельных систем). 

Но, ....

Comment: @avp А вопрос можно? Спасибо. Вопрос: зачем? Что, мало языков и компиляторов к ним? Питон хорош так, как он есть. Делать из него что-то не питоновое, на мой взгляд, не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: @alexlz, вот уж не думал, что из моего коммента можно сделать такой вывод.

Прямой ответ:


    Берем питон. Ничего не меняем (в языке). Пристально  вглядываемся. Понимаем, что *на самом деле хотел* программер (ну, написал он что-то на питоне, но мы резгадывем его *истинные* намерения).

       Производим максимально эффективный код.  


Разве это не достойная задача?

Comment: @avp "Производим максимально эффективный код" на C++? Как это называется, написание прототипа на питоне (или другом каком языке, где писать легче, а машинная эффективность хуже)?